# Where can I find an information about how much all public npm packages is weight?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

And have someone such package.json with dependency of all packages? I'm asking without any jokes. Can't find any useful information about it on top of Google results.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking.  Are you trying to find out how many total lines of code in every public npm?  There are well over a million such packages, so I doubt anyone knows, nor is there any reason to know.

Answer (score 0):

depends what are you looking for... :D
you can find size of each package for npm packages on https://www.npmjs.com/
but in app there is some VSCode plugins which on imports show you sizes of packages

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost

Comment: It is some kind of mad to get size of each of one million packages =] So I want to know ready data or want to know how can I parse it if it possible